# Adding site to "Allowed to play sound" by Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

**Settings > Privacy and security > Site Settings > Sound > Allowed to play sound > Add**

By following the above path in Google Chrome we can add domains to allow auto playing Sound for a specific website.

Is it possible to add websites programmatically to this interface by Google Chrome extension APIs?

Comment: I've read the docs, but that may not be possible. [chrome.contentSettings](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/contentSettings/)